# Array of numbers sort is wrong

Tags: javascript

today I found something interesting about array prototype `sort`.

```
var numbers = [1,7,23,11,50,60];
```

So I created an array of numbers and wanted to sort them. So I used

```
console.log(numbers.sort()) //-> [1, 11, 23, 50, 60, 7]
```

The result was weird, `[1, 11, 23, 50, 60, 7]`. What is wrong with the sort function?

```js
var numbers = [1,7,23,11,50,60];
alert(numbers.sort())
```

Comment: It seems to be a precise duplicate. The **reason** is that by default `sort` sorts elements as strings. The first answer to the duplicate question, in its very first sentence, states "By default the sort method sorts elements alphabetically.".

Comment: @torazaburo I just missed that line, sorry. Although I searched for any answers probably I didn't see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sort()` will call `toString()` on all members and thus they get converted to string and you get the wrong sort order.

you'll have to manually pass a comparator.

```
function comparator(x,y) {
    return x - y;
}

numbers.sort(comparator);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort by integer just do it like this. The compare Function of the normal sort converts the integer to string and then compares them.

```
function sortNumber(a,b) {
   return a - b;
}

var numArray = [1,7,23,11,50,60];
numArray.sort(sortNumber);
```

Output

```
[1, 7, 11, 23, 50, 60]
```